# How to get current user with Discourse API

Tags: python, urlfetch, discourse

I'm accessing the [Discourse API](http://docs.discourse.org/) from python using [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests). The **Get a single user by username** endpoint requires a GET request such as `/users/{username}.json`

From a browser, this command returns a json response as expected, however from an API call like:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch('{}/users/{}.json'.format(domain, username))
```

it returns a HTML page. I've even tried setting the content type to application/json:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
result = urlfetch.fetch('{}/users/{}.json'.format(domain, username), headers=headers)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved:**

Need to add api_key and api_username to GET request:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch('{}/users/{}.json?api_key={}&api_username={}'.format(domain, username, discourse_api_key, discourse_api_username))
```